# position absolute fluid design

Tags: fluid

This is a fluid design of 4 images (width = 160px) with ul or floated divs.
 
Everything is well when resizing window. It's fluid.

But when i pass to an absolute position, i find no more 160px initilally

Code:

> body        { position:relative;}       .container {
>         /*position:absolute; left:0; top:0;*/ /* remove this comment to see
>   differnce */
>                         margin: 0; padding:0; border:black 1px solid; max-width:690px; overflow: hidden/*clear floated childs*/;}   .galleryItem {      float:
>   left; width: 23%; margin:0 1%; padding:1% 0;}     .galleryItem img {
>     max-width: 100%;}       ul { list-style:none;}  ul.thumbs
>   {     /*position:absolute; left:0; top:100px;*/ /* remove this comment to
>   see differnce */
>                         display:block; margin: 0; padding:0; border:black 1px solid; max-width:690px; overflow: hidden/*clear floated childs*/;} 
>     ul.thumbs>li{       display:block; float:left; width: 23%; margin:0 1%;
>   padding:1% 0;}    ul.thumbs>li img{   display:block; max-width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

I think not to mix the % and px  for the liquid design. 
And knowledge that i have i can say that if position is absolute then there is something is fixed so no liquid.
if you want liquid design better to do positioning in %.
you can have the bootstrap css too for responsive design.